# How would one prove that the following scheme definition is an ordered stream of integers

Tags: proof-techniques, functional-programming, induction

How would one prove that the following scheme definition is an ordered stream of integers

```
(define integers (cons-stream 1 (add-streams ones integers)))
```

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  We want to help you understand concepts, not do your exercise for you.  We want to help, but as it stands you haven't given us much to work with.  Knowing how to help you probably requires knowing what you've tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: Like what @D.W. says. Moreover, I googled your definition and found some further explanation (as well as the missing definitions of the stream `ones` and the operator `add-streams`).  So what is your precise problem?